# C programming Control reaches end of non-void / segmentation fault

Tags: c

I'm having trouble with a function which aim to add a node at the end of a list. It seems to work fine in a main()
Problem is : I have a segmentation fault after when i call this function in bison file. The **gdb** debugger clearly states that the error come from this function. 
When I compile w/ -Wall -Werror i'm having the error `control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]`

Here is my function :

```
int addNode(Node *n, list List) {
  list *pList = (list *)malloc(sizeof(list));
  *pList = List;

  if (List == NULL) {
    List = n;
  } else {
    while (((*pList)->next) != NULL) {
      pList = &((*pList)->next);
    }
    (*pList)->next = n;
    return (0);
  }
}
```

I saw on another thread that returning a **int** `return(0);` instead of **void**  at the end could solve the error, but in my case it doesn't work.
If someone have a hint 
Thanks in advance

Comment: `list* pList = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    *pList = List;` This line makes no sense to me. Anyways you are returning `0` only in the `else` part.

Comment: if `next` is a pointer, in  `pList = &((*pList)->next);` the ampersand is redundant and causing error.

Comment: What is `list`? Do you know what pointer is?

Comment: `control reaches end of non-void function` **means your function is not returning anything when it is expected to do so.**

Answer (score 1):

```
list *pList = (list *)malloc(sizeof(list));
*pList = List;
```

you want

```
list *pList = &List; /* There is no need to call malloc */
```

> control reaches end of non-void function

Because you don't return anything  when `(List == NULL)`

This is wrong:

```
    while(((*pList)->next) != NULL){
            pList = &((*pList)->next);
    }
```

`pList` is a pointer, not a pointer to pointer, change to:

```
    while (pList->next != NULL) {
            pList = pList->next;
    }
```